# Returning list from Data.Binary.Get

Tags: haskell, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read MIDI files as an educational exercise in dealing with binary files, but I have run into a snag.

When I read tracks, I want to only grab a specific number of tracks as declared in the header portion of the file. Here is my code on how I tried to solve it (doesn't work though):

```
getMidi = do
  header <- grabHeader
  tracks <- grabTracks (numTracks header)
  return (header, tracks)

grabTracks :: Integer -> Get [Track]
grabTracks numT = do
  if numT == 0
     then do
       return []
     else do
       myTrack <- grabTrack
       otherTracks <- grabTracks (numT-1)
       return myTrack : otherTracks

grabTrack :: Get Track
grabTrack = do
  chunkId <- getByteString 4
  chunkSize <- getWord32be
  events <- getLazyByteString (fromIntegral chunkSize)
  return Track {trackSize=(fromIntegral chunkSize), eventData=events}
```

`numT` is the number of tracks as declared in the header file. I want to do it this way for two reasons.

1. There may be garbage at the end I want to ignore.
2. Want to apply this technique to other binary files where there is a list of "somethings" inside of it.

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Get [a]' with actual type `[a0]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return myTrack : otherTracks
    In the expression:
      do { myTrack <- grabTrack;
           otherTracks <- grabTracks (numT - 1);
           return myTrack : otherTracks }
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if numT == 0 then
          do { return [] }
      else
          do { myTrack <- grabTrack;
               otherTracks <- grabTracks (numT - 1);
               return myTrack : otherTracks }
```

I don't know how to make a `Get` monad when I am forced to use list concatenation like this. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses

```
return (myTrack : otherTracks)
```

in order to have the line not be parsed as

```
(return myTrack) : otherTracks
```

Function application binds stronger than any infix operator.

In the first version, you return a list in the `Get` monad, in the second, you have an expression of list type in a do-block whose other statements are `Get`s.

Comment: That fix worked perfectly! I forgot about function precedence there. I don't really know why anyone would use `(return myTrack) : otherTracks` (or what that would mean, I should say).

Comment: Well, if you construct a list of `IO Track` or something, it could make sense to have some elements be just `return someTrack` instead of nontrivial actions. But most of the time, `return something : somethingElse` is just a mistake and should have used parentheses or `($)`.

Comment: The `($)` thing is probably why I thought my previous code was correct. I just see it in `print` statements all the time, even though I ignore the `$` everytime. I eventually just found out that the `$` was a super low-precedent function applicator. Thanks again!